# If $a_{n}$ converge to $0$ and $|b_{n}-b|\leq a_{n}$, show that $b_{n}\rightarrow b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof 
let $\epsilon > 0$
since $a_{n}$converge to 0
we have

$$|a_{n}|<\epsilon $$

and

$$|b_{n}-b|\leq a_{n}$$

but $|a_{n}|<\epsilon $

then $|b_{n}-b|\leq a_{n}< \epsilon $ or$ |b_{n}-b|< \epsilon $ or limit is b

Comment: Your proof should start with "let $\epsilon>0$ be given"

Comment: What is $n$? What you've written certainly true for *every* $n$, so which do you mean?

Comment: You should add that after some $n_0 \in \Bbb N$, $|a_n| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: You're almost there. Just remember that $a_n\geq |b_n-b|\geq 0$ and so $a_n=|a_n|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the idea of the steps is correct, but it should be written down a bit more carefully.

If $a_n\rightarrow 0$, then $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists n_0$ s.t. $\forall n\geq n_0$ $|a_n|\leq\epsilon$.

Since $|b_n-b|\leq a_n$, we have that $\forall \epsilon>0\exists n_0$ s.t. $\forall n\geq n_0$ $|b_n-b|\leq|a_n|\leq\epsilon$, which is the definition of $(b_n)$ converging to $b$.

Note that I wrote that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0$ such that the inequalities hold for all $n\geq n_0$. It is not true that $|a_n|\leq\epsilon$ for all n, only after a certain $n_0$ this will be true, and the smaller you make $\epsilon$, the larger (in general) this $n_0$ will have to be chosen.